# Pick keys from object which contains specific string as substring in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, lodash

I am having an array like:

```
var arr = ["hello","world"] 
// This array can contain any number of strings
```

Object like this:

```
var obj_arr = {
  "abc-hello-1": 20,
  "def-world-2": 30,
  "lmn-lo-3": 4
}
```

I want to have an object which contains only those keys, which contains above array values as substrings.
For eg:

Result will look like :

```
var result = {
  "abc-hello-1": 20,
  "def-world-2": 30,
}
```

I want to do something like this (using lodash) :

```
var to_be_ensembled = _.pickBy(timestampObj, function(value, key) {
  return _.includes(key, "hello");
  // here instead of "hello" array should be there
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With lodash you can use [`_.some()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some) to iterate the strings arrays, and to check if the key includes any of the strings.

```js
const arr = ["hello", "world"]

const timestampObj = {
  "abc-hello-1": 20,
  "def-world-2": 30,
  "lmn-lo-3": 4
}

const to_be_ensembled = _.pickBy(timestampObj, (value, key) =>
  _.some(arr, str => _.includes(key, str))
);

console.log(to_be_ensembled);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using only javascript you can acheive this using  array `forEach` & Object.Keys function

```js
var arr = ["hello", "world"]


var obj_arr = {
  "abc-hello-1": 20,
  "def-world-2": 30,
  "lmn-lo-3": 4
}

var resultObj = {};
// get all the keys from the object
var getAllKeys = Object.keys(obj_arr);
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  // looping through first object 
  getAllKeys.forEach(function(keyName) {
    // using index of to check if the object key name have a matched string
    if (keyName.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
      resultObj[keyName] = obj_arr[keyName];
    }
  })
})
console.log(resultObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
var result = _.map(arr, function(s){
  return _.pickBy(timestampObj, function(v, k){
    return new RegExp(s,"gi").test(k)
  })
})
```